# How can I get values of chekcboxes if I use cellrenderer function with ag grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, listcellrenderer, getvalue

Due to can not use angular ng-model for checkboxes in cellrenderer function, I can not get their values. So I changed my code

```
return `<input  type='checkbox' ${params.value.disable ? 'disabled' : ''} ${params.value.state ? 'checked' : ''} />`;
```

But I want to get values of them when I press the GET button. How can I get their values?

Note: I used someone plunker with my changes to save time:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YjVlFYaOJJxS0mOIR6nu?p=preview

Comment: You need to get values or selected rows or all rows in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your render function have an issue there is no value for `params.value.disable` and `params.value.state` if you need to assign the data value to the `checked` attribute change it to `params.value` as below

```
return `<input  type='checkbox' ${params.value.disable ? 'disabled' : ''} ${params.value ? 'checked' : ''} />`;
```

You can get a list of selected rows using `$scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()`.

And if you can iterate through all the `rowNodes` in the grid and and get its values use `$scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function(rowNode, index) { });`

```
$scope.getValues= function(){

    var selectedRows = $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
    selectedRows.forEach(function(selectedRow, index) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(selectedRow));
    });


    $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function(rowNode, index) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(rowNode.data));
    });

}
```

For more details check [Grid API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/)

Comment: But I dont select rows, selecting only checkboxes. Also   $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode how can access to checkboxes values? I could not find?

Comment: For example, if you need to get the value of `read` checkbox `rowNode.data.b` as `b` if the field name.